# Installing MySQL on Snow Leopard using MacPorts

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard, mysql5

I am trying to install MySQL5 on Snow Leopard, but I am having some trouble. Here is my terminal log:

```
users-MacBook-Pro:~ sam$ sudo port install mysql5Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for mysql5
--->  Fetching mysql5
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for mysql5
--->  Extracting mysql5
--->  Applying patches to mysql5
--->  Configuring mysql5
--->  Building mysql5
--->  Staging mysql5 into destroot
--->  Installing mysql5 @5.1.53_0
The MySQL client has been installed.
If you also want a MySQL server, install the mysql5-server port.
--->  Activating mysql5 @5.1.53_0
--->  Cleaning mysql5
users-MacBook-Pro:~ sam$ sudo port install mysql5-server
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for mysql5-server
--->  Fetching mysql5-server
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for mysql5-server
--->  Extracting mysql5-server
--->  Configuring mysql5-server
--->  Building mysql5-server
--->  Staging mysql5-server into destroot
--->  Creating launchd control script
###########################################################
# A startup item has been generated that will aid in
# starting mysql5-server with launchd. It is disabled
# by default. Execute the following command to start it,
# and to cause it to launch at startup:
#
# sudo port load mysql5-server
###########################################################
--->  Installing mysql5-server @5.1.53_0
******************************************************
* In order to setup the database, you might want to run
* sudo -u _mysql mysql_install_db5
* if this is a new install
******************************************************
--->  Activating mysql5-server @5.1.53_0
--->  Cleaning mysql5-server
users-MacBook-Pro:~ sam$ sudo chmod -Rf 777 /opt/local/var/db/mysql
chmod: /opt/local/var/db/mysql: No such file or directory
users-MacBook-Pro:~ sam$ sudo chmod -Rf 777 /opt/local/var/db/mysql5
users-MacBook-Pro:~ sam$ sudo -u _mysql mysql_install_db5
Installing MySQL system tables...
ERROR: 1004  Can't create file '/var/tmp/#sqlf2ef_1_0.frm' (errno: 9)
110125 20:22:45 [ERROR] Aborting

110125 20:22:45 [Note] /opt/local/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete


Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in
/opt/local/var/db/mysql5 for more information.

You can try to start the mysqld daemon with:

    shell> /opt/local/libexec/mysqld --skip-grant &

and use the command line tool /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysql
to connect to the mysql database and look at the grant tables:

    shell> /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysql -u root mysql
    mysql> show tables

Try 'mysqld --help' if you have problems with paths.  Using --log
gives you a log in /opt/local/var/db/mysql5 that may be helpful.

Please consult the MySQL manual section
'Problems running mysql_install_db', and the manual section that
describes problems on your OS.  Another information source are the
MySQL email archives available at http://lists.mysql.com/.

Please check all of the above before mailing us!  And remember, if
you do mail us, you MUST use the /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqlbug script!
```

I have tried repairing the my disks permissions but nothing seems to work :( Would appreciate any advice on how to get MySQL up and running!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /opt/local/var/db/mysql5
sudo chmod u+rwx,go= /opt/local/var/db/mysql5
sudo /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
```

If you're having problem setting the root password, reset it using the instructions found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix

For starting and stopping the mysql daemon I use the following aliases:

```
alias mysql_start='sudo /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5/mysql5.wrapper start';
alias mysql_stop='sudo /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5/mysql5.wrapper stop';
alias mysql_restart='sudo /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5/mysql5.wrapper restart';
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, Reimund's answer here didn't solve it.  However, first running as `root`:

```
sudo mysql_install_db --user=root
```

then setting the permissions as they should be:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:admin /opt/local/var/db/mysql5
sudo chmod u+rwx,go= /opt/local/var/db/mysql5
```

did the trick.

Answer (score -2):

Why not try using the [dmg image](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads)

Comment: Tried that. I couldn't get it to start for whatever reason.

Comment: Downvoted because suggestions without rationale are not very useful.